# Android animations back to back on different elements

Tags: android, animation

I'm looking to start the same animation on different TextViews 1 after the other after a set duration of time. Currently I have the code below but I feel that there must be a better way to do this.

```
      Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flyin);
      play_now_but.setAnimation(anim);

      Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flyin);
      anim2.setStartOffset(250);
      story_mode_but.setAnimation(anim2);

      Animation anim3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flyin);
      anim3.setStartOffset(500);
      create_puzzle_but.setAnimation(anim3);

      Animation anim4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flyin);
      anim4.setStartOffset(750);
      stats_but.setAnimation(anim4);

      Animation anim5 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flyin);
      anim5.setStartOffset(1000);
      settings_but.setAnimation(anim5);

      Animation anim6 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flyin);
      anim6.setStartOffset(1250);
      about_but.setAnimation(anim6);

      anim.start();
      anim2.start();
      anim3.start();
      anim4.start();
      anim5.start();
      anim6.start();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's nothing wrong with the way you did it, although I would start the next animation explicitly when the previous one has finished:

```
Animation anim = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flyin);
play_now_but.setAnimation(anim);

final Animation anim2 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flyin);
story_mode_but.setAnimation(anim2);

final Animation anim3 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flyin);
create_puzzle_but.setAnimation(anim3);

final Animation anim4 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flyin);
stats_but.setAnimation(anim4);

final Animation anim5 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flyin);
settings_but.setAnimation(anim5);

final Animation anim6 = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(this, R.anim.flyin);
about_but.setAnimation(anim6);

anim.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        anim2.start();
    }
});

anim2.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        anim3.start();
    }
});
anim3.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        anim4.start();
    }
});
anim4.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        anim5.start();
    }
});
anim5.setAnimationListener(new AnimationListener() {
    public onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) {
        anim6.start();
    }
});

anim.start();
```

Comment: There's no simpler way using perhaps a for loop and array? This implementation although technically correct just seems wasteful

Comment: @MattStokes You can certainly do this in a loop in an array - as long as you add your buttons to an array.